# read array from plist through shell script plist buddy

Tags: ios, shell, plist

I have written shell script which reads array from plist.

```
PLIST_PATH="./../Documentation/documentation.plist"
echo "PATH = $PLIST_PATH"
FILE_ARRAY=`/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "print :'public-headers'" $PLIST_PATH`
```

Now I want to retrieve all the strings from this array but i am not able to get count from this array.

please help.

Comment: What does that command produce?

Comment: FILE_ARRAY Value is  : Array {
    test.h
    test2
    35146514
}

Comment: I want to get these values in loop.

Answer (score 5):

The safe way is to iterate thru the array with individual Print statements for the indexes until no key is found anymore.
The script below prints the number of entries in the given array key and plist

```
PLISTBUDDY="/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c"
if [ "$#" -ne 2 ]; then
  echo "usage: $0 <array key> <plistfile>"
  exit 1
fi
KEY=$1
PLIST=$2
i=0
while true ; do
   $PLISTBUDDY "Print :$KEY:$i" "$PLIST" >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
   if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
      echo $i
      break
   fi
   i=$(($i + 1))
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Any array from your command will return an array of the form -

```
Array {
    1
    2
}
```

`sed` will remove first and last line, so with this -

```
declare -a FILE_ARRAY =($(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "print :'public-headers'" $PLIST_PATH | sed -e 1d -e '$d'))
```

you will get `1 2`, which you are declaring as an array in `FILE_ARRAY`

which you can access as - `${FILE_ARRAY[1]}`

Length of such array will be - `echo ${#FILE_ARRAY[@]}`

[Source of the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40881834/609782)