# Get Array of Values using plistBuddy

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell, plistbuddy

```
var="keychain-access-groups"
declare -a val=$( /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print $var" "sample.plist")
echo ${val}
echo ${val[0]}
```

Ouput:

```
Array { ABCD.com.bus.NoEntitlements ABCD.com.bus.sharing }
Array { ABCD.com.bus.NoEntitlements ABCD.com.bus.sharing }
```

How to get the first item in the Array?

Answer (score 3):

It seems `PlistBuddy` produces output like this:

```
Array {
    ABCD.com.bus.NoEntitlements
    ABCD.com.bus.sharing
}
```

That is, multiple lines. If you want to get to the elements of the `Array`, you need to first slice off the first and last lines:

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy | sed -e 1d -e '$d'
```

Next, to read this into a Bash array, you need to surround the `$(...)` subshell with another `(...)`, like this:

```
declare -a val=($(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy | sed -e 1d -e '$d'))
```

After this, you can access the first value with `${val[0]}` and the second value with `${val[1]}`.